# How to Compare two rows in excel sheet?

Tags: asp.net, excel, c#-4.0

I am having an excel sheet in which i need to compare two adjacent rows ? How to compare it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly: `rows` are considered equal why? Because every `cell` equals.

```
int equalCount = 0;

for(int i=0; i < row1.Fields.Count; i++){
    if(row1[i] == row2[i]){
        equalCount++;
    }
}

if(equalCount == row1.Fields.Count){
    // row/cells equal.
}
```

This compared every row1 cell to the same row2 cell.

*Side note:* I'm not sure if your code uses .Fields / .Columns / .Cells so it's purely illustrative.